# SQL Server Polybase with multiple files

Tags: polybase

I want to use PolyBase to read a directory of csv or xlsx files with similar schemas but different file names. File names has pattern such 'subjectXYZ_yyyy-mm-dd'.
The files are added daily and I don't want to create an External Table per file.
How I should set ODBC DSN and/or PolyBase DataSource/External Tables parameters for this?

Comment: I'm actually currently working on this very same kind of task; the default MS ODBC drivers are problematic, I'm trialling the CSV ODBC driver from CData. I'm building a framework to use configuration that defines a table schema, path, file etc and dynaimcally checks for and creates external data source names and external tables. I create a data source per folder location and can optionally choose to create an external table per file schema or drop and create as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Polybase / External tables support either single file names or folders in the `LOCATION` argument, but the files **must** be the same structure.  A simple example using CETAS (but the principle is the same):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext.lineitem_1995
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'enriched/tpch/tpch10/lineitem_partitioned/1995',
    DATA_SOURCE = [MyDataSource],
    FILE_FORMAT = [ParquetFF]
) AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.lineitem
WHERE YEAR(l_shipdate) = 1995;
```

Comment: I think this is working for HDFS/Azure Blob. I can't use this for ODBC with local file system.